# How to automate two os.Stdin input using Bash

Tags: bash, go

I need to automate the input of a code segment like bellow where the inputs of the ReadString are distinct.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    buf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    value, err := buf.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }

    buf = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    value, err = buf.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

I have tried several formats like the bellow one following answers of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line), unfortunately, none worked.

```
>> echo "data1
data2" | go run main.go
output: data1

        EOF
```

Here `data1` and `data2` and input of the separate ReadString methods. I don't have control over the source code. So, I can only try changing the bash input. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the second string does not end with a newline. Looking at the documentation for `ReadString`:

> If ReadString encounters an error before finding a delimiter, it returns the data read before the error and the error itself (often io.EOF).

So, even though error is non-nil, you have the data. The following change should work for this specific case:

```
buf = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
value, err = buf.ReadString('\n')
if value!="" {
    fmt.Println(value)
}
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

In general, even if you get an error from `ReadString`, you may still have nonempty data returned from the function.

Comment: I have tried using the following command also-
```
  echo "data1
  data2
  " | go run main.go
```
it returns the same EOF just like the previous one. 
I don't have control over the source code. So I can only try changing the bash input.

Comment: then you need a newline after data2.

Comment: Being buffered, the first reader probably reads the whole input, so when you create the second reader there's nothing to read. Do not create a second reader, use the first one.

Comment: If you look at this: https://golang.org/src/bufio/bufio.go?s=1757:1793#L51, default buffer size is 4096, so unless your input is at least 4096 bytes, it'll read the whole thing, so there's nothing left to read for the second reader.

Comment: I also thought probably this is happening. But I don't have control over the program code. Is n't there any way to generate the input for this kind of scenario?

Comment: Try two very long lines, longer than 4k.

Comment: How about using something like EOF to mark the end of input of a single Stdin?

Comment: Why is the code written like this? The program appears to be buggy.

Comment: This a very simplified version of a complex project. I need to automate this portion mainly.